# prove that (Ha)(Hb)=Hab iff H is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra

if H is a subgroup of G prove that (Ha)(Hb)=Hab for all right cosets Ha and Hb of H in G iff H is normal in G

Comment: How is $(Ha)(Hb)$ being defined?

Comment: there is no more information in the question

Comment: Why should the definition of $(Ha)(Hb)$ be in the question? Surely it is given in your textbook or lecture notes!

Comment: Not sure whether it is best to close this as being off-topic for lack of context or as a dup. I was searching for a suitable duplicate. Found that "gem", and stopped looking. If you feel another closure reason is better, I can fix that :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $(Ha)(Hb)$ consists of all elements of the form $h_1ah_2b$, for $h_1,h_2\in H$.

Suppose $H$ is normal in $G$. We want to show that $(Ha)(Hb)=Hab$.

*Proof that $(Ha)(Hb)\subseteq Hab$*.
Let $h_1,h_2\in H$. Then $h_1ah_2b=h_1ah_2a^{-1}ab$. If $h=h_1ah_2b=h_1ah_2a^{-1}=h_1(ah_2a^{-1})$ we see that, by normality, $h\in H$. Therefore $h_1ah_2b=hab\in Hab$.

*Proof that $Hab\subseteq (Ha)(Hb)$.*
Let $h\in H$; then $hab=1a(a^{-1}ha)b$. Set $h_1=1\in H$ and $h_2=a^{-1}ha\in H$; then $hab=h_1ah_2b\in(Ha)(Hb)$

Suppose $(Ha)(Hb)=Hab$, for all $a,b\in G$. We want to show that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in H$. Then $ghg^{-1}=1ghg^{-1}\in (Hg)(Hg^{-1})$. Since $(Hg)(Hg^{-1})=Hgg^{-1}$ we know there exists $h_0\in H$ such that
$$
ghg^{-1}=h_0gg^{-1}
$$
Therefore $ghg^{-1}=h_0\in H$.

Answer (score 0):

$\impliedby$: If $H$ is normal, then $a^{-1}Ha=H$ for any $a \in G$, so $(Ha)(Hb) = (Ha)(a^{-1} H a b) = Hab$.

$\implies$: Taking $a=g^{-1}$ and $b=g$ for some $g \in G$ gives $H g^{-1} H g = H$. Thus $g^{-1} H g \subset H$ (for any $h \in H$, there exists $h' \in H$ such that $1g^{-1} h g = h'$). Similarly, taking $a=g$ and $b=g^{-1}$ gives $HgHg^{-1}=H$; for any $h \in H$, there exists $h' \in H$ such that $1gh g^{-1}=h'$, so $h=g^{-1} h' g$, showing that $H\subset g^{-1} H g$.

Comment: thanks alot but what i did not anderstand is "for any h∈Hh∈H, there exists h′∈Hh′∈H such that ghg−1=h′ghg−1=h′" why is that

Comment: @Ahb It follows from the equality $H g^{-1} H g = H$. $1g^{-1} h g$ is an element on the left-hand side, and the equality implies that it is equal to some $h' \in H$.